# Laravel + vuejs refresh page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I developing applications with laravel and vue.js.

Already works but when I want to refresh the single page applications on the browser I get a blank page.

On laravel I have this on web.php

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function (){
    return view('vue');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

And on vuejs router is the traditional configuration.

I work on phpstorm and with PHP artisan serve command.

If I test my vue.js applications alone already works if I refresh this page.

How to make the same scenario with laravel.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? And also how are you importing your JS assets in your base view?

Comment: No error in the console. I import assets with mix laravel on blade view

Comment: I've found the error, is JSON parsing problem. Thx